# Saving custom objects to a plist with NSCoder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, nscoding, initwithcoder

So, I've realised that I need to use NSCoding to save my custom objects to a plist.

The part I'm struggling with is exactly how I do that after I've implemented the `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder` methods. They return `id` and `void` respectively, so if they've converted my objects into NSData or whatever they do to them, where's the data, so I can save it?

I have the methods set up thusly:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder { // Decode
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"gameName"];
        self.genre = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"gameGenre"];
        self.rating = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"gameRating"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder { // Encode
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"gameName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.genre forKey:@"gameGenre"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.rating forKey:@"gameRating"];
}
```

Trying to figure out what the next steps are to get these objects (which are already in an NSMutableArray) saved to a .plist, and recalled when re-opening the app.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that depends on what you want to do.  It's possible that `NSKeyedArchiver` will be sufficient.  Consider:

```
+ (NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)rootObject
+ (BOOL)archiveRootObject:(id)rootObject toFile:(NSString *)path
```

which takes a root object of an object graph and either creates a NSData object with the serialized data, or serializes the data to a file.

Then look at `NSKeyedUnarchiver` which has these:

```
+ (id)unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)data
+ (id)unarchiveObjectWithFile:(NSString *)path
```

I'm sure that will get you on your way toward your goal.

**EDIT**

> I'm hitting an error when trying to (I think) tell it which array I
>   want it to write. Getting "Expected identifier" on this line:
>   [rootObject setValue:[self.dataController.masterGameList]
>   forKey:@"games"]; – lukech

That's a KVC API.  The archive/unarchive methods are class methods, so you just save your entire object graph with:

```
if (![NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.dataController.masterGameList
                                 toFile:myPlistFile]) {
    // Handle error
}
```

and then you load it with:

```
self.dataController.masterGameList =
    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myPlistFile];
```

Comment: I'm hitting an error when trying to (I think) tell it which array I want it to write. Getting  "Expected identifier" on this line:

`[rootObject setValue:[self.dataController.masterGameList] forKey:@"games"];`

Comment: Is `self.dataController.masterGameList` the root object of the object graph that you want to persist?  If so, then you would archive that object, e.g. `NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.dataController.masterGameList];`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement `NSKeyedArchiver` on the root object of your object graph to save and then `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to reconstitute the object graph.

See [this tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php)

Comment: The tutorial's centered around Mac stuff rather than iOS, but I'm hitting an error when trying to (I think) tell it which array I want it to write. Getting  "Expected identifier" on this line:

`[rootObject setValue:[self.dataController.masterGameList] forKey:@"games"];`